# Python files on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I downloaded a python file and edited in BBedit. Now that I'm trying to access it from terminal, it does not appear as an executable file (green). It's white instead. And when I run a tool that makes use of it, it says that the python executable cannot be found. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Have you installed python?

Comment: Either add executable permissions to that file or run it as `python filename`

Comment: Python files are not supposed to be executable. If you don't have python on your machine, you have messed up your system badly and need to reinstall the operating system. It is possible that whatever tool you are using needs a different version of Python than the one included with OS X, though. Check the documentation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why do you say *"Python scripts ard not supposed to be executable"* please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first line is a valid shebang, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Then make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x YourScript.py
```

Then run it with:

```
./YourScript.py
```

or put it anywhere on your `PATH` and run it with:

```
YourScript.py
```